# Is it possible to call a child function in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, recursion, parent

We have the following recursive function:

```
parent "function"
  {
  if (main condition)
  {
  if (condition1) call a child "function";
  if (condition2) call a child "function";
  if (condition3) call a child "function";
  if (condition4) call a child "function";
  } Else {
  exit from child function and return to the position in which she had been called in the parent function;
  }
  }
```

How to implement it?

Comment: That is exactly how you implement it, except for the details of the syntax.

Comment: You haven't explained yourself well enough to answer the question.

Comment: My implementation without else. What should be in esle to work? I'm using ARC.
http://i065.radikal.ru/1211/53/61176c0e5d64.png

Comment: You need to describe your intent better.  What you show above would work, if it describes your intent.  (Seems to me that all you need in the `else` clause is `return` -- which would also occur without the `else` clause -- though you may want to return a value that can be tested on the caller side to further direct your program flow.)

Comment: Example - http://s51.radikal.ru/i134/1211/96/f0575c14a32e.png

Comment: Suppose given a 5x5 field. There are 6 non-empty cells. We need to find all the ways with adding single cell. You can only add to a neighboring cell. Analogue of this code works on pascal...

Comment: http://s47.radikal.ru/i117/1211/3f/14f4c8a0af21.png